# Unable to amend the Visible Property

Tags: vba, excel

I am using the following code at the start of a script to unhide a very hidden sheet within Excel.

But I am getting an error saying I am unable to amend the visible property. (Screen shot of error message)

I am basically trying to unhide the sheet & then once the sheet has been update it make it very hidden again.

Any help?

Thanks
Al

[image]

```
Sheets("UserActive").Visible = xlVisible
```

Comment: is it the only workbook loaded? if not, check the workbook that is currently active is the correct one. If there is only one workbook, check the spelling for the sheet

Comment: Try: **Sheets("UserActive").Visible =xlSheetVisible**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either of the below statement should work. Please check the spelling of worksheet name.
Worksheets("UserActive").Visible = -1

or

Worksheets("UserActive").Visible = xlSheetVisible

Comment: or .visible = true , wich should be 1 , not -1

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Sheets("UserActive").Visible = true
```